# How to create map of java POJO class/ Json String having primitive data?

Tags: java, json, pojo

I want to make a **Map** (String ,Object) like this

`{AssessmentId=0, Physical_name='ram', Physical_height=20, Physical_weight=60}`

from my Pojo Class - **InitialAssessment**

```
public class InitialAssessment  {

    private long AssessmentId;

    private String physical_name;

    private String physical_gender;

    private int physical_height;

    private float physical_weight;


// all getter And setter is Created here

}
```

without using any **external Library like Gson** etc.

Comment: reflection is one way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
public Map getMapFromPojo(InitialAssessment assessment) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    if (assessment != null) {
        Method[] methods = assessment.getClass().getMethods();

        for (Method method : methods) {
            String name = method.getName();

            if (name.startsWith("get") && !name.equalsIgnoreCase("getClass")) {
                Object value = "";

                try {
                    value =  method.invoke(assessment);
                    map.put(name.substring(name.indexOf("get") + 3), value);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    return null;
}
```

It will give you map for pojo class like this:

**Output:**

```
 {AssessmentId=0, Physical_name='ram', Physical_gender='Male' , Physical_height=20, Physical_weight=60}
```